# In SQL query, how to add alias name in the where condition

Tags: mysql

Alias name can be used in the condition with the keyword HAVING, but how to use more than one alias name in the condition.

Comment: Uhm, rephrase your question, it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

the **having** filter the result of the query, and therefor can use the alias

the **where** filter the data before the result, and therefor can't use the alias from the result.

you probely can go around the problem by using a subquery, but that probely whould lower the performens, so i recomendate to just copy paste the statement you have put an alias on.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query is not parsed from top to bottom like functions in a development language. The `SELECT` part is not the first thing to be evaluated, but rather it starts from the `FROM` part together with JOINs (if any), then `WHERE`, etc. The `SELECT` part is processed somewhere at the end. For that reason you cannot user alias in the WHERE part of the query and `HAVING` is processed after SELECT.